# The site linking item in the ‘Reputation’ FAQ entry may be wrong (or the system doesn't work as advertised)

Tags: support, reputation, linked-accounts, association-bonus

Following on from [my earlier question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50425/) (solved, thanks!), I still think perhaps the wording in the [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/) FAQ entry about linking accounts is wrong.

It seems to me that

- the site you are linking FROM must
  have at least 200
- the rep in the
  site you are linking TO will be
  boosted by 100 (not the one you are
  linking FROM) *(I could be wrong here,
  I don't know what happens if the one
  you are linking to already has 200+ rep)*
- it should be OR not AND. The current
  wording sort of implies that you need
  to link to all 4 to get 100 bonus rep
  points.

I suggest this wording instead:

- Linking accounts between Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User and meta from any account with at least 200 reputation: **+100 reputation on each site linked to**

This reflects my recent experience, at least. Whether it is the desired behaviour is up to people other than me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have 100 rep and you should be able to edit the FAQ itself, if you like.. as it is community wiki. Per the /faq:

> Amass enough reputation points and Meta Stack Overflow will allow you to go beyond simply asking and answering questions:
>
> **100**  Edit community wiki posts

Comment: Ha! Good point, will do. Amusingly, I didn't have enough points rep until I got the site linking around the right way.